# How to make a list of the coordinates of all columns and rows

Tags: python, python-itertools

Suppose I have a `n x n` grid, and I want a function that generates a list of all columns and rows by taking `n` as the input, in python. By a list of columns, I mean each column is represented as its own list, with elements being coordinates of the elements in the column. (Or each column could be a set of coordinates, that would work too)

I could do this using two list comprehensions,

```
x = [[ (i, j) for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)] + [[ (i, j) for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
```

With `n=3` this produces a list with 9 elements, each of which is a list of 3 coordinates.

```
x = [[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2)], [(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)], [(2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0)], [(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1)], [(0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2)]]
```

I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to do the same thing, maybe using itertools or a similar module.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure if this is what you're looking for but you could try `itertools.product`
For example

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> n = 3

>>> list(product(range(n),range(n)))
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]

>>> [list(product(range(n),range(n)))[n*i:n*i+n] for i in range(n)]
[[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2)], [(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)], [(2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]]

>>> [list(product(range(n),range(n)))[i::n] for i in range(n)]
[[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0)], [(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1)], [(0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2)]]
```